# Is it possible to use http scheme with desired port say 6500 instead of ws and wss scheme in WebSockets?

Tags: javascript, html, sockets, protocols, websocket

I would like to know,

if there is any way possible to use `http://` scheme instead of `ws://` or `wss://` schemes for `Websockets` in HTML5, if not then why not?

What are the various ways to declare Websockets in HTML5 and using custom protocols?

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Using WebSockets means using the WebSocket protocol; there is no way to circumvent that.

Comment: Hey pimvdb thanks for the responce I said custom protocol because this website talks about using custom protocols and also using http instead of ws and wss but i have also read that ws and wss are the only once alowed have a look at this url https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications from Mozilla's developer reference

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  But the server is supposed to respond with `Connection: upgrade` and then switch to the WebSocket protocol.  Unless you're proxying the request.  It'll use `HTTP CONNECT` to maintain a tunnel, but the idea is that WebSocket traffic uses the WebSocket protocol. ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket))

That page from MDN is draft and shouldn't be used as reference.  It's rather incomplete.

Have a look at [socket.io](http://socket.io) if you're thinking about doing a WebSocket client/server.  It's a rather well built implementation with fallback.